# passing php varible in strip charg

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, strip

I want to pass php variable in stripe but they show error missing param amount.

Here is my code i get this amount from previous page and want to pass amount variable in this code but i search on the net they said pass only cent value.
 Is there any solution to pass amount through variable i want to pass value dynamically not static how is it possible

```
    $amountvalue = '123';
     try {
        if (empty($_POST['street']) || empty($_POST['city']) || empty($_POST['zip']))
          throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
        if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
          throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
        Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $amountvalue,
                                    "currency" => "aud",
                                    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                    "description" => $_POST['email']));
        $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                    <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful.
                    </div>';
      }
      catch (Exception $e) {
        $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                  <strong>Error!</strong> '.$e->getMessage().'
                  </div>';
      }
```

But it seems Stripe wont except this variable. it puts a 'Missing required param: amount' error on the page It only wants to accept a actual integer such as '1234'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESuQo.png)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Have you tried `$amountvalue = 123;`

Comment: i just want to pass varible in

Comment: Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount" => $amountvalue,
                                    "currency" => "aud",
                                    "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                    "description" => $_POST['email']));

Comment: but its show error missing param amount

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my second comment?

Comment: yes i am trying by using this but same error

Comment: i search on net i found just passing cent value as e.g

Comment: 400 , 500 etc but i want to pass dynamic value

Answer (score 0):

If, according to you, the **Stripe_Charge::create()** Static method only wants Numeric data and not String; then you can as well simply feed it Numeric data too, like so:

```
    <?php
        // THIS IS EXACTLY THE SAME CODE YOU SUPPLIED ABOVE WITH JUST A SIMPLE CHANGE:
        // THIS TIME WE ARE USING CENTS RATHER TO MAKE IT EASIER.
        $amountvalue = '123';
        try {
            if (empty($_POST['street']) || empty($_POST['city']) || empty($_POST['zip']))
                throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
            if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
                throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");
            // NOTICE THAT THE ONLY CHANGE HERE IS TO WRAP THE $amountvalue INSIDE OF intval()
            // THIS CONVERTS THAT $amountvalue TO AN INTEGER, 
            // REGARDLESS OF WHETHER IT IS DYNAMIC OR HARD-CODED AS IT IN THIS CASE.
            // NOTICE ALSO THAT WE ARE MULTIPLYING THE PASSED AMOUNT BY 100
            // THAT IS CONVERTING THE $amountvalue TO CENTS...
            Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount"      => intval($amountvalue)*100,
                                        "currency"    => "aud",
                                        "card"        => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                        "description" => $_POST['email']));
            $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                        <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful.
                        </div>';
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                      <strong>Error!</strong> '.$e->getMessage().'
                      </div>';
        }
```

**Stripe requires that you pass a source Parameter** ***containing the Credit Card Data*** like so:

```
    \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      "amount" => 400,
      "currency" => "usd",
      // YOU'RE NOT PASSING THIS source ARRAY PARAMETER...
      // YOU'RE PASSING JUST card INSTEAD... PROBABLY THE CREDIT-CARD NR. ONLY
      "source" => array(
        "number" => "4242424242424242",
        "exp_month" => 5,
        "exp_year" => 2017,
        "cvc" => "314"
      ),
      "description" => "Charge for test@example.com"
    ));
```

Reference: https://stripe.com/us/features

If your Function is truly **NUMBER HUNGRY**, it will smile with that little change there... ;-)

Cheers & Good Luck....

Comment: Error! Invalid positive integer

Comment: @flower   I edited the code, this time using Cents instead... You may want to give a try if you will...

Comment: Error! Invalid positive integer

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh! Now I see... the issue is that you need to pass ***You are passing  card instead of source...***

Comment: plz check this screen short

Comment: actaully amount passsing from another page using and i get amount in this page and passing amount varible in function not directly integer value

Comment: just hardcode the amount  as integer eg: "amount" => 100 and try

Answer (score 0):

The Problem does not seem to be the amount but the data you pass in your create function. Look at this code:

```
<?php

        // THIS IS EXACTLY THE SAME CODE YOU SUPPLIED ABOVE WITH JUST A SIMPLE CHANGE:
        // THIS TIME WE ARE USING CENTS RATHER TO MAKE IT EASIER.
        $amountvalue = '123';
        try {
            if (empty($_POST['street']) || empty($_POST['city']) || empty($_POST['zip']))
                throw new Exception("Fill out all required fields.");
            if (!isset($_POST['stripeToken']))
                throw new Exception("The Stripe Token was not generated correctly");

            Stripe_Charge::create(array("amount"        => intval($amountvalue)*100,
                                        "currency"      => "aud",
                                        //HERE WAS THE ISSUE:
                                        'source'        => array(           
                                            "number"    => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                            "exp_month" => $_POST['expiry_month'],  // GET THE CORRESPONDING POST VALUE FOR EXPIRY MONTH
                                            "exp_year"  => $_POST['expiry_year'],   // GET THE CORRESPONDING POST VALUE FOR EXPIRY MONTH
                                            "cvc"       => $_POST['cvc']            // GET THE CORRESPONDING POST VALUE FOR EXPIRY MONTH
                                        ),
                                        // REMOVE THIS ENTRY: "card"
                                        // "card"          => $_POST['stripeToken'],
                                        "description" => $_POST['email']));

            $success = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                        <strong>Success!</strong> Your payment was successful.
                        </div>';
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                      <strong>Error!</strong> '.$e->getMessage().'
                      </div>';
        }
```

You just need a way to get and pass-in the Credit-Card information: **Credit-Card Number, Expiry Month, Expiry Year and CVC**. I believe that would solve your problem...